# Intellij Idea Code Style - Insert blank line after closing curly brace

Tags: intellij-idea, coding-style

I want Idea to insert a blank line after a closing curly brace when I format the code.

So this,

```
if(condition1)
{
    someMethod();
}
else
{
    anotherMethod();
}
statement1;
statement2;
```

would end up as this

```
if(condition1)
{
    someMethod();
}
else
{
    anotherMethod();
}

statement1;
statement2;
```

I went through the Code Style dialog, but couldn't find the relevant option.

Comment: It seems to be no such an option, unfortunately (still, in 2019). The same in auto-formatting inline comments with space after `//`.